# KnockoutJS json object/observable "visible" binding not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to configure a rather complex model to bind a view to using KnockoutJS.

Here is a problem markup section:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="visible: dialogSelectedCode.HasValue, value: dialogSelectedCodeValue"/>
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(dialogSelectedCode)"></span>
```

input element is never shown, but my "debug" span shows the contents

```
{"Code":"{intInc_G}","HasValue":true}
```

What is the correct way to bind a visible of my input in case the "decision"-data is hidden inside JSON object?

UPDATE: Here is a rather complex [fiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/mpavlov/LHzny/16/). To get to the problem dialog, run the fiddle, click "Add block" and try choosing several items in the drop down input (especially first and the second one - since they clearly show that `dialogSelectedCode` variable is indeed being updated.

Comment: Could you please supply some more code (i.e. ViewModel definition)

Comment: It is enormous by now. I will figure out a fiddle to showcase the problem in a few minutes =)

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov It needs to be observable for the `visisble` property to update when it changes. Putting it in JSON will not work.

Comment: I've updated the question body to include the fiddle that can showcase the problem. Thanks in advance for looking at it.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov That fiddle is insane. My previous comment stands, it won't update because `HasValue` is not observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create a computed for the HasValue property.  Your binding `dialogSelectedCode.HasValue` does not follow the observable, it checks for the HasValue on the observable *function*.  The property way `dialogSelectedCode().HasValue` throws an error.  Creating a computable and letting it do the tests [works](http://jsfiddle.net/xgsqU/):

```
self.dialogSelectedCodeHasValue = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedCode  = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.dialogSelectedCode);
    return selectedCode && selectedCode.HasValue;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. My understanding was that it would work the way I set it up, since even though .HasValue wasn't an observable, `dialogSelectedCode` was indeed, and that entire value was actually changing every time drop box item is selected. Now I know it doesn't work that way.